# What system runs High Adventure Cliffhangers: The Buck Rogers Adventure Game?

Tags: buck-rogers

Was the [*High Adventure Cliffhangers: The Buck Rogers Adventure Game*](http://rpggeek.com/rpg/1732/the-buck-rogers-adventure-game) compatible with [*Buck Rogers XXVc*](http://rpggeek.com/rpg/1145/buck-rogers-xxvc) game? From what I understand XXVc was a simplified AD&D 2e system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Probably Not

Looking around a little bit, it seems you're right- Buck Rogers XXVc appears to use a modified AD&D system ([source](http://weirdscifi.ratiosemper.com/buckrogers/xxvc.html)).

However, High Adventure Cliffhangers appears to use an exploding d6 system ([source](http://www.darkshire.net/jhkim/rpg/encyclopedia/alphabetical/H.html) - scroll down to the entry on High Adventure Cliffhangers). You can actually see a note to this effect in the RPGGeek entry for the game:

> RPG Mechanic:
>
> Attribute/Stat Based (STR, CON, PER, etc)
>
> Dice (Primarily d6)
>
> Exploding Dice (Die may 'explode'into a second roll)
>
> Skill Based (buy or gain skills)

Answer (score 1):

Those links actually imply the answer: RPGGeek doesn't group them in the same system family so, unless there's an error in the entries, they are very probably unrelated.